# Translate code from 5 digit to 3 char

Tags: c, algorithm, math, compression

I have a code composed of five decimal, I need to store (compress) it in a field that can only contain 3 alpha numeric ascii printable characters . Is it possibile to have a bidirectional conversion between the two fields ? How in C ?

Comment: Assuming 'five decimal' means five digits in 0..9, and '2 alpha numeric' means two characters in 0..9A..Z, then there are 10^5 = 100000 possibilities for the former, and 36^2 = 1296 possibilities for the latter, so there can't be a one-to-one mapping.

Comment: @RoryDaulton thanks, got to it in the edit grace period :)

Comment: I'm sorry for previous request

Comment: Assuming upper and lower case letters, and digits, you have 26+26+10 = 62 characters in your output alphabet.  So this is basically a problem of converting base 10 to base 62.  Take your input number `% 62`.  That's the last "digit" of your 3-character representation.  Convert that digit to `A-Za-z0-9`.  Continue with the standard divide-and-remainder base conversion algorithm.

Comment: @SteveSummit could you give me an example in c ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To represent any number from 0 to 99999 with three digits, you would need to convert the number from base 10 to a higher base *b*, where *b*<sup>3</sup> > 99999.

The smallest base that meets this requirement is 47. There are 97 printable ASCII characters to choose from, so clearly there's no problem.

Incidentally, if you're converting numbers into strings that will be visible to users, you might want to consider selecting characters that have no chance of forming unfortunate strings like `bum`.

The following code should work. It isn't optimized, but should be fast enough unless you need to convert millions of numbers per second.

```
#define ALPHABET "26789BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTVWXYZbcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz"
#define LEN_ALPH 47

unsigned int asc2int(char *s) {
    unsigned int i, result = 0;
    while (*s) {
        for (i=0; i<LEN_ALPH; i++) {
            if (*s == ALPHABET[i]) break;
        }
        if (i == LEN_ALPH) return 0; /* Illegal character in input */
        result = result * LEN_ALPH + i;  /* TODO: Check for overflow */
        s++;
    }
    return result;
}

char *int2asc(unsigned int n) {
    static char result[7];  /* Should be sufficient for any 32-bit input */
    char *ptr = result+6;
    *ptr = '\0';
    if (n == 0) {
        *(--ptr) = ALPHABET[0];
    }
    else {
        while (n) {
            *(--ptr) = ALPHABET[n % LEN_ALPH];
            n /= LEN_ALPH;
        }
    }
    return ptr;
}


int main() {
    unsigned int tests[10] = { 0, 1, 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 11111, 12345, 54321, 99999 };
    unsigned int i, n;
    char *s;

    /* Test with selected numbers */
    for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
        s = int2asc(tests[i]);
        n = asc2int(s);
        printf("%u -> %s -> %u\n", tests[i], s, n);
    }

    /* Test all numbers */
    for (i=0; i<100000; i++) {
        if (asc2int(int2asc(i)) != i) {
            printf("Failed at i=%u\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's wrong with bum? Did you mean to point out that bum can be confused with bvm? Or more like b0m with bOm?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow "Bum" is an Englilsh word that means "buttocks" or "anus", so it's not the sort of thing you want to have as a user ID.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible, unless you are willing to use upper and lower case letters as well as the digits.

There are 90,000 such codes with exactly 5 decimals, and the cube root of that rounded up is 45. So a single alpha-numeric character would have to have 45 possibilities.

So in your case consider using Base64 encoding, which has emerged as a standard in itself: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: I'm sorry for previous request

Comment: The whole set of printable ascii characters is fine, also upper and lower case letters